# Jquery AJAX function always returning false

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

both my JS and PHP file work correctly, the problem i'm having is that it **ALWAYS** says error with submission even when I see the PHP script resulted in outputting "proceed". The database insert works correctly from the form and count stores the numbers of rows in my table. Is there something i'm overlooking?

### JS

```
var dataString = $("form").serialize();
var msg = '<?php echo $msg; ?>';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'submit_form.php',
    data: dataString,
    datatype: 'html',
    error: function() {
        alert('Error');
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        if (msg == 'proceed') {
            $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
            $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>").append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>");
        }
        else {
            $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
            $('#message').html("<h2>Error with Submission!</h2>").append("<p>Please Try again.</p>");
        }
    }
});
return false;​
```

### PHP

```
if ($count > 15)
{
    $msg = 'error';
    echo $msg;
    exit();
}
elseif ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Comments (Name, Email, Comment) values (?, ?, ?)"))
{
    //do sql logic here 
    $msg = 'proceed';
    echo $msg;
}
else
{
    /* Error */
    printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

Comment: `return false` always returns false..

Comment: What is with your php formatting?

Comment: Add one alert(msg) in the function(msg){ too see the responde..

Comment: @Esailija you get the idea though, the else conditional block is the one running even when the data is "proceed"

Comment: Any reason for not using drupal's AHAH or AJAX (d7) in form API?

Comment: @Asad that's a different function, functions never share return statements. The success function doesn't even have a return statement though.

Comment: @Esailija `it ALWAYS says error with submission even when I see the PHP script resulted in outputting "proceed"` is the actual problem. Focus on this. Ignore the returned false value.

Comment: Please add: error: function (jqXHR, status, error) { alert(jqXHR + ": " + status + " :" + error); } and post the result of that so we see the actual error

Comment: @Asad use `dataType: "text"`, note it's `dataType`, not `datatype`. If you use `"html"`, jQuery would turn the response into jQuery object before returning it to you, which always ends up in the else branch because jQuery object is not equal to any string (except `"[object Object]"` in a loose comparison lol)

Comment: @Esailija That could be it, post it as an answer and see whether the OP confirms

Comment: datatype must be with capital letter T >  dataType

Answer (score 2):

You might be outputting whitespace or other characters along with your "proceed" response, which would make the condition in the success handler false.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataString = $("form").serialize();
var msg = '<?php echo $msg; ?>';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'submit_form.php',
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'html',
    error: function() {
        alert('Error');
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        if (msg == 'proceed') {
            $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
            $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>").append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>");
        }
        else {
            $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
            $('#message').html("<h2>Error with Submission!</h2>").append("<p>Please Try again.</p>");
        }
    }
});
return false;​
```

Try this ?

Comment: It should not be  `"html"`, it should be `"text"`. This is technically the same what he already had since with misspelled `datatype`, the type is inferred from the content-type header sent from server, which is `text/html` by default

Answer (score 0):

Try this : use trim to clean response

```
success: function(msg) {
    if ($.trim(msg) == 'proceed') {
        $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
        $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>").append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two of the most common reasons I've seen that your ajax could always be running the error method.

```
 dataType=json
```

if it's not json remove this line

```
  async : true
```

consider changing this around

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the error is in php not ajax.

Define $MySQLi at the top of submit_form.php and try ;)